# Set timer to pause

Tags: delphi, timer

How can I pause `TTimer` in Delphi with keeping interval? So, for instance, I have `TTimer` that has **10 seconds interval** and when I set timer to pause **after first 7 seconds** of working, it will save its state, and then when I resume timer it will **fire after remaining 3 seconds**.

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Combine Remy Lebeau's answer and relativ's answer and you have your solution :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot do that with a `TTimer` which is a loose wrapper around the `SetTimer` API.

In order to do this you would need to keep track of when the timer started and when you paused it. Then you would know how much time was left. When you need to pause, set the timer `Enabled` property to `False` and set the interval to be the amount of time remaining. Don't forget that after the timer fires for the first time you need to reset its interval to the true interval.

As you can see from the above, a `TTimer` is not the best fit for your problem. But, having said that it would not be terribly difficult, and quite fun, to produce a `TTimer` variant that supported pausing the way you desire.

Comment: He said interval is 10 second! If he need to calculate how much time is left before paused the timer , he must need to set interval of timer is 1 second . Otherway he doesn't know how much time left! Best answer is mine. For your answer David he still need to set interval of settimer API is 1 second. Don't need to waste time accept my answer, David already have 79k :))

Comment: @relativ resolution of timer api is typically around 50ms. I liked your answer. That's why I upvoted it.

Comment: @sertac I'm not sure what you are getting at.

Comment: @David - I had the impression that your answers were consistently having unreasonable down votes. I thought the votes might be coming from a specific user, SO have got measures to prevent such serial down-voting. I may be wrong of course..

Comment: @Sertac I think the serial downvoting has diminished. There's always going to be a bit of hard to explain voting. The one that got me yesterday was on the I/O checks option question but the accepted answer was updated to be very comprehensive so that was resolved very well.

Answer (score 13):

```
Timer.interval :=1000;
ICount:integer;
```

In create procedure set icount to 0

```
Procedure timerevent(sender:tobject);
Begin
    If icount=10 then
    Begin
       // do proccess
     Icount = 0;
   End;
   Inc(icount);
End;
```

Now you can stop the timer anywhere

Comment: +1 Creative solution. Resolution is only 1 second but that may be fine.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how the Windows timer facility works, and that's not how the Delphi wrapper works, either.

When you disable the timer, keep note of how much time was remaining before it was due to fire again. Before you re-enable it, set the `Interval` property to that value. The next time the timer fires, reset `Interval` to the original value.

Answer (score 1):

`TTimer` does not support what you are asking for.  As others have already commented, you would have to stop the timer, reset its `Interval` to whatever time is remaining, start it, then stop and reset its `Interval` back to 10 seconds when the next `OnTimer` event is triggered.

A simpler solution is to just let the `TTimer` keep running normally, and have a separate flag that tells the `OnTimer` event handler whether it can do its work or not whenever it is triggered, eg:

```
var
  Boolean: Paused = False;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  if not Paused then 
  begin 
    // do proccess 
  end; 
end; 

procedure TForm1.PauseButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Paused := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.ResumeButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Paused := False;
end;
```

Comment: This won't meet the requirements of the question as highlighted in bold.